# [ansible-playbook]specified line no longer in file, maybe it changed?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have an ansible-playbook and when i try to run this playbook i am getting this error
(specified line no longer in file, maybe it changed?)

```
--
- name: check if the public/private key exist at ~/.ssh/
  stat:
    path: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  register: st

- name: run the command
  command: cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub|ssh -i /root/.ssh/bi_ppc.pem ubuntu@"{{items}" "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
  with_items:
    - groups['ubuntu']
  when: st.changed
~
```

ansible --version

```
ansible 2.2.0.0
  config file = /home/swathi/Desktop/infrastructure/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `authorized_key` module, copy pub key from local to remote.

```
--
- name: get public key
  local_action: shell cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  register: pubkey

- name: check keys
  debug: msg="{{ pubkey.stdout }}"

- name: add public key on the remote server
  authorized_key: user=root key="{{ item[0] }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item[1] }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ pubkey.stdout }}"
    - "{{groups['ubuntu']}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error message from ansible:

```
$ ansible-playbook t.yml 
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unexpected end of stream

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible/t.yml': line 6, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

(specified line no longer in file, maybe it changed?)
```

The playbook is:

```
$ cat t.yml 
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "unterminated quoted string
```

In fact there is a YAML syntax error, at the end of the playbook missing a double quote. As it finish the playbook my editor doesn't help me by showing a different color.

Hope that will help someone else.